# Serilog - .Net Core 3.1 - Console Application - Not logging to file (but logging to console)

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, serilog

I am trying to add logging functionalities to a .Net Core 3.1 Console application using Serilog. I have setup the Logger configuration in the code itself (not appsettings.json as of now). I have tried various combinations, but, to my surprise, every time it is logging to the Console window only but not to the file.

I have enclosed the Logger inside using block as suggested in few articles but still no luck. Could you please let me know what I am missing here? Thanks.

Here is my Main Method:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var logger = BuildSerilog())
            {
                try
                {
                    logger.Information("It's logging to the console but not in the file.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Fatal(ex, "Application crashed");
                }
            }
        }

        private static Logger BuildSerilog()
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .WriteTo.File("app.log")
                            .WriteTo.Console()
                            .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger = logger;

            return logger;
        }
```

Nuget Packages referenced in the project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Comment: Where do you expect the app.log file to be created?

Comment: In the same location where the application is running (i.e. inside the root folder of Program.cs)

Comment: No. Check it inside bin/debug or bin/release folder

Comment: OMG.. you are correct. It's creating inside bin/Debug folder. How can I give the path so that it will create in my intended location (i.e. in the root folder)?

Comment: I suggest make it configurable using config file

Comment: I was already having the appsettings.json (but, commented as I thought it was not working). Now, I modified the code & it is reading the settings from the json file and logging to the file as well. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Consider adding the resolution as the accepted answer